# What could be the reasons for BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Using the in-app billing v3 library and the `IabHelper` from the example provided, I get the response `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` (3) after running `mHelper.startSetup(myOnIabSetupFinishedListener)`.

I've signed the application, uploaded it, created an store item, waited the required 2-3 hours (actually waited 24 hours) and I'm testings it on a device with a single Google account that is in the tester's list.

What does this error mean? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check 
Maybe ...

```js
Check 
Maybe ...
No need: Inapp
skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,getPackageName(), "Inapp", querySkus);


Need: inapp
skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```